# Dispatch is not a function in Server Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a problem with redux-thunk, it just doesn't pass the dispatch to my action creator. I'm logging it but it is still undefined:

Here is my action creator:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import Service from '../service'



export const fetchFromApi = payload => {
  return { type: types.FETCH_FROM_API_TEST, payload }
}


export const fetchApiTestAction = () => dispatch => {
  return Service.GetUsers().then( _data => {
    dispatch(fetchFromApi( _data.data )) // you can even distructure taht like fetchFromApi(({ data }))
  }).catch ( err => {
    // error catching here 
    // you can even call an failure action here...
    // but sorry about it , i have no time for that , im sorry :(
    throw (err)
  })
}
```

Here is my Service.js class

```
// Basic fetch
  async basicFetch(url, options, headers = this.authernticateHeader) {
    let fetchOptions = {}
    if(options.headers) {
      fetchOptions = {
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        ...options
      }
    } else {
      fetchOptions = {
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        ...options,
        headers
      }
    }


    // log before sending the request...
    // console.log(url, fetchOptions, fetchOptions.headers.get('Content-Type') )

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${this.serverAddress}${url}`,
        { ...fetchOptions }
      )

      if(!response.ok) {
        throw {
          message: response.statusText,
          api: `${options.method} ${this.serverAddress}`
        }
      }

      const responseJson = await response.json()
      console.log('----------------------------')
      console.log(responseJson)
      console.log('----------------------------')
      return responseJson
    } catch(err) {
      throw { ...err }
    }
  }


  GetUsers = () => {
    return this.basicFetch(this.urls.GET_USERS, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
  }
```

Here is my routes.js file

```
import { fetchApiTestAction } from './actions/fetchApiTestAction'



const routes = [

  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home,
    fetchInitialData: fetchApiTestAction()
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    component: Contact
  },

]
```

And here is my server.js file

```
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {

  const activeRoute = routes.find( route => matchPath(req.url, route) ) || {}

  const _promise = activeRoute.fetchInitialData 
    ? activeRoute.fetchInitialData()
    : Promise.resolve()

  _promise.then( () => {

    const store = configureStore()
    const markup = renderToString(

      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </StaticRouter>
    )

    const initialBrowserTabText = 'hi there from home page...'
    const initialState = store.getState() || {}

    const _template = template( initialBrowserTabText, initialState, markup )

    res.send(_template)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
})
```

I haven't faced this kind of problem so far. When I `console.log(dispatch)` inside of my action creator (before `return` part) it is undefined. I should say that here is what my terminal shows to me:

```
Server is listening on port 8000...
----------------------------
{ page: 1,
  per_page: 3,
  total: 12,
  total_pages: 4,
  data: 
   [ { id: 1,
       first_name: 'George',
       last_name: 'Bluth',
       avatar: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg' },
     { id: 2,
       first_name: 'Janet',
       last_name: 'Weaver',
       avatar: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg' },
     { id: 3,
       first_name: 'Emma',
       last_name: 'Wong',
       avatar: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg' } ] }
----------------------------
TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/js/actions/fetchApiTestAction.js:17:7)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

This means that I'm getting the data from api, but why dispatch is not a function?

Comment: Why would it be a function in the first place? You are running `fetchInitialData` even before you configure the redux-store... `dispatch` is a property of the redux-store, if you don't have a redux-store, then you can't `dispatch`... Also, notice that `activeRoute.fetchInitialData` is not a thunk... If it was a thunk it would be dispatched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work unless you pass the redux-store `dispatch` property when you invoke `fetchInitialData`... Something like this:

```
  const _promise = activeRoute.fetchInitialData 
    ? activeRoute.fetchInitialData(store.dispatch)
    : Promise.resolve()
```

The real problem is that your redux-store doesn't even exist at that point, because you are configuring it after that promise has finished... So that's something else that you will have to address.

Comment: first off, thank you for your respond, but how can i configure my store that it could be available for server side at the time that server needs to dispatch an action to fetch data from an endPoin??? that `fetchInitialData` ends up in my service.js config file , how that could be possible to instantiate store in my service.js file? how could it possible?

Comment: you are a masterpiece  , take care of your self , and many many many thanks for answering me the god damn right answer. love you...